# Warning: cWorld "may not respond to '+alloc'

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am just starting out with Objective-C but have done a bunch of C++.  Its haunting me because I keep messing up my Objective-C syntax.

I am getting a crash creating my first Objective-C object.  I think it may be related to this warning on the alloc function.

```
cWorld may not respond to '+alloc'
```

I've seen lots of fixes for '-alloc' but nothing for +alloc.  Anyone have any idea what might be causing it?

The crash is in asm code, I don't get much info.  The warning is on the line in worldContext.mm seen below... //***** WARNING IS HERE

This is a snippet from worldContext.mm and all of world.mm + world.h

worldContext.mm

```
#import "worldContext.h"
#import "scenemanager.h"
#import "matrix4.h"
#import "world.h"

@implementation cWorldContext

- (void)Initialize {

    mSceneManager = new cSceneManager();


    mWorldObj =[[cWorld alloc] init];    //***** WARNING IS HERE
    [mWorldObj Initialize: mSceneManager];
}
```

World.h

```
#ifndef __WORLD
#define __WORLD

class cModelBase;
class cSceneManager;

@interface cWorld {

    cSceneManager* mSceneManager;
    cModelBase* mWorldModel;
}

- (void)Initialize: (cSceneManager*) sceneManager;
- (void)Update;
- (void)Shutdown;

@end

#endif
```

World.mm

```
#import "world.h"

@implementation cWorld


- (void)Initialize: (cSceneManager*) sceneManager {

    mSceneManager = sceneManager;
}

- (void)Shutdown {

}

- (void)Update {

}

@end
```

Comment: Two comments:  1) You don't need a .mm file unless you're mixing Objective C and C++ in the same file -- a .m file will suffice for the implementation, 2) You might find Google's Obj-C style guide helpful:  http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml

Comment: @mharper given how he's creating the `mSceneManager` in "WorldContext.mm", it would appear he's using Objective-C++.  Agree on the style though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@interface cWorld {
```

Should be

```
@interface cWorld : NSObject {
```

Comment: +1.  If you want to call `NSObject` methods from your class, you need to inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: You'll also want to name your class `CWorld`, not `cWorld`;  classes start with uppercase letters (method with lowercase).